# Easiest way to make a draggable floating icon in Flutter over all pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a floating action button or the like to be draggable. The icon should be like a ball that can be kicked. For example if user swipes the icon quickly it will goes and hit the sides of the screen, image the screen is a pool and the icon is the pool ball.
Any good ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try this package, it suits what you want
https://pub.dev/packages/floating_draggable_widget